# gpg-agent is not requested in git calls

Tags: git, gnupg

In git commits (gpg), *git* command always asks for passphrase while *gpg-agent* is running.

I launch *gpg-agent* with

```
$ eval `gpg-agent -s --enable-ssh-support --daemon --write-env-file $HOME/.gpg-agent-info`
```

Then I open another terminal and check it's running:

```
$ cat ~/.gpg-agent-info
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/gpg-w2HH4r/S.gpg-agent:28539:1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/gpg-QQTJCD/S.gpg-agent.ssh
SSH_AGENT_PID=28539
$ ps -u $USER | grep gpg-agent
28539 ?        00:00:00 gpg-agent
$ echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO $SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SSH_AGENT_PID
/tmp/gpg-w2HH4r/S.gpg-agent:28539:1 /tmp/gpg-QQTJCD/S.gpg-agent.ssh 28539
$ echo test | gpg-aes -t D2FA51BD --use-agent | gpg --use-agent
....
test
....
```

The first '**....**' says that it's needed a passphrase and *gpg-agent* launchs *pinentry-gtk-2*. The last '**....**' says that *gpg* is signing with the key ID.

> Running again the same command don't asks for passphrase

.

But when running git, **gpg** asks for the passphrase in the command line, **not gpg-agent with pinentry**:

```
$ echo test >> test.txt ; git add test.txt ; git commit -S -m "test"
....
(intro passphrase)
....
```

> Running again (and again...) the same command always asks for
>   passphrase (to the same key ID).

My *.gitconfig* only has set the **user name** and **email**. Both commands (*gpg* and *git*) asks for the same key ID. Calling *gpg* with *--use-agent* works fine (without it not), but *git* has no options to pass to *gpg* (only user config values in *.gitconfig*); and the environment is correct.

Logging *gpg-agent* with **debug-level 8** only shows activity with *gpg* command, but nothing with *git*.

I'm using *gnupg 1.4.12* and *gpg-agent 2.0.19* (Debian Wheezy stable, official repos).
I've cloned git from github repo, compiled and installed locally the current versión (2.3.0.rc1.30.g76afe74) with the same results.

I've checked my configs but I've no idea what kind of problem is this. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Silly me...
Setting option **use-agent** in *gpg.conf* solves the issue.

**Git** doesn't check if *gpg-agent* is running and *gpg* needs to be called with the option **--use-agent**.

I must change my default GPG behavior (options)... and use **--no-use-agent** in other scenarios.

Comment: I have use-agent on my conf file but it is still not called by git commands.